# RaspberryPi.Net Libary LCD Display

Tags: hardware, display, debian, mono, c#

So my problem is, that we want to control a LCD (HD44780) Display with our Raspberry Pi Model B V1.1. The Libary seems to have a support for it. But there only seems to be one example in the whole web. (https://github.com/cypherkey/RaspberryPi.Net#liquid-crystal-display) And we are idiots. Can someone give a better explanation how to do this?

Comment: I'm looking at that example, and it doesn't look *that* bad. What happens when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple examples on using the HD44780 display with Raspberry Pi, you just have to use a more commonly used tag for the display - the 2x16 (which obviously refers to 2 rows of 16 characters).

It often also helps to look for examples on YouTube, where you will find videos showing working examples together with code explanation.

Comment: The Problem is, that we need to use the RaspberryPi.Net Libary for the Project. It's hard to find something on that. On Youtube I only find mostly python examples.

Comment: Why is that particular library needed?

Comment: School, Teacher, Stuff.